# Reset textarea height in javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have a textarea (auto resizing) and I want to clear all of its contents including its height.

So far I've tried:

```
document.getElementById('textarea').value = '';
```

And :

```
document.getElementById('textarea').attribute('rows','1');
```

But both doesn't work.

**EDIT :**

I use autosize.js with this :

```
<textarea id="post" rows="1" title="Write something..." name="posttxt" placeholder="Write something..." role="textbox" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML that defines your textarea?

Comment: Please show the html code or the name of the library you re using to create this auto resizing textarea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `setAttribute` to reset `style` attribute added automatically during the resize :

```js
document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function(){
    var textarea = document.getElementById('target');
  
    textarea.setAttribute('style','');
    textarea.value = "";
}
```

```html
<textarea id="target" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the style:

```
document.getElementById("textarea").style.height = "20px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a JQuery version, that I'm using when I close a modal on my project

```
$("#jobURL").attr("style", "").val("")
```